# Derivative of the following matrix with respect to a vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives

$$J=X^T(Q\otimes I) X+U^T(Z\otimes I)U$$

$\frac{\partial J}{\partial U}=? $

where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product.

$X$ is a vector which depends on vector $U$.

$Q, Z$ is a positive semi-definite matrix,

$I$ is identity matrix.

superscript $T$ is the transpose of the matrices.

**My try:**

$\frac{\partial U^T(Z\otimes I)U}{\partial U}=(Z\otimes I)U+(Z\otimes I)^TU $

it is right?

$\frac{\partial X^T(Q\otimes I)X}{\partial U}=?$

Comment: $X$ should be a vector, not a matrix. Right?

Comment: Dear @Greg, You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've correctly calculated
$$\frac{\partial(U^T(Z\otimes I)U)}{\partial U}=(Z\otimes I)U+(Z\otimes I)^TU\,\,=A$$
Simply replacing $(U,Z)$ by $(X,Q)$ yields
$$\frac{\partial(X^T(Q\otimes I)X)}{\partial X}=(Q\otimes I)X+(Q\otimes I)^TX\,\,=B$$
And although you haven't told us, I assume that you know the relationship between $X$ and $U$ and are able to calculate the matrix $C=\frac{\partial X}{\partial U}$

All that's left is to combine these 3 quantities to obtain the desired gradient. 
$$\eqalign{
dJ
 &= A:dU + B:dX \cr
 &= A:dU + B:(C\,dU) \cr
 &= (A + C^TB):dU \cr
\frac{\partial J}{\partial U} &= A + C^TB \cr
}$$ For ease of typing, I used a colon to denote the inner/scalar product.

Comment: Thank you. Then, is the following right? ($X_1$ is a real vector) $$\frac{\partial\big((X+X_1)^T(Q\otimes I)(X+X_1)\big)}{\partial U}=\big[(Q\otimes I)(X+X_1)+(Q\otimes I)^T(X+X_1)\big]C\,\,$$

Comment: Almost, the RHS should be $\,\,C^T[\ldots]\,\,$ instead of $\,\,[\ldots]\,C$

Answer (score 1):

Derivatives should be understood under the context of linear approximation. Then

\begin{align*}
dJ
&= (dX)^T (Q \otimes I) X + X^T (Q \otimes I) dX \\
&\quad + (dU)^T ( Z \otimes I ) U + U^T ( Z \otimes I) dU
\end{align*}

As for $dX$, we may invoke Jacobian $\operatorname{Jac}(X) = \left( \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial U^j} \right)$ to write $dX = \operatorname{Jac}(X) dU$. Then

$$ dJ = (dU)^T \left[ \operatorname{Jac}(X)^T (Q \otimes I) X + (Z \otimes I) U \right] + \left[ X^T (Q \otimes I) \operatorname{Jac}(X) + U^T (Z \otimes I)\right] dU. $$

If needed, one may read out the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial J}{\partial U^j}$ from the identity above.